# duplicate id in onClick when processed in cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out how to fix it. I have this json `[{'key': 'data', 'id': '3213'}, {'key': 'data', 'id': '7684'}]` and need 'id' transfer to onClick. I generete with help a cycle:

```
this.array_container = []
for (var key in json) {
   array_container.push(
      <div onClick={() => this.func(json[key]['id'])}><p>json[key]['key']</p></div>
   )
}
```

and render

```
render() {
   return (this.array_container)
}
```

The problem is that  the second 'id' is change the 'id'  in first container in the onClick. Two container is have same id in the onClick. What mistake?
Json is have different id, that's for sure

Comment: That's not JSON, it's an array of JavaScript Objects

Comment: Associative array, but why id is dublicate?

Comment: There are no Associative arrays in JavaScript

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider accepting one of them if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `map`

```
this.array_container = [];
json.map((obj) => {
   this.array_container.push(
      <div onClick={() => this.func(obj.id)}><p>{obj.key}</p></div>
   )
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the error code:  change to <div onClick={() => this.func(obj.id)}><p>{obj.key}</p></div>

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the argument inside the arrow function. This will fix the issue:

```
{/* -----------vv--------denote--vvvvvvvvvvvvv--- */ }
<div onClick={(id) => this.func(json[key]['id'])} key={key}>
   <p>json[key]['key']</p> {/* ---also don't forget ^ key */}
</div>
```

This will solve two issues:

1. Without passing argument, the function will take same value on each loop. Passing argument will solve the issue to work with the relevant key.
2. Passing key property will avoid showing warning in the console. You should always pass the key props whenever you render array of elements.

---

Better way to handle event is to use like this:

```
onClick={(e, id) => this.func(e, json[key]['id'])}
```

You can now even listen to the event object.

Or, without using arrow function:

```
onClick={this.func(e, json[key]['id'])}
```

You can now write a public class method inside your component class:

```
func = id => e => {
  //...
}
```